# Two statements next to curly brace in an equation

Tags: latex

How can I write an equation with one curly brace (`{`), and on the right-hand side next to the curly, two statements in two different lines?

Comment: Why is this question in stackoverflow rather than in tex.stackexchange ? Though it is answered there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can try the `cases` env in amsmath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $x<0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: amsmath cases]

Comment: @Lucho Is it possible to have two different numbers to these two equations on the right?

Answer (score 26):

That can be achieve in plain LaTeX without any specific package.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is your only binary choices
\begin{math}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      0\\
      1
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

This code produces something which looks what you seems to need.

[image: curly braces in front of two lines]

The same example as in the @Tombart can be obtained with similar code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{math}
  f(x)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      1, & \mbox{if $x<0$}.\\
      0, & \mbox{otherwise}.
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{math}

\end{document}
```

This code produces very similar results.

[image]

Comment: This solution gives an output identycal to the `cases` environment of `amsmath`, except for a slightly smaller curly brace, which sometimes can be an advantage.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for

```
\begin{cases}
  math text
\end{cases}
```

It wasn't very clear from the description. But may be this is what you are looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Continuation_and_cases

Comment: As @Lucho indicated you need \usepackage{amsmath}, but I assume you are using it anyways. The packages amsmath, amssymb and amsthm are hard to do without when typesetting math.

Answer (score 8):

To answer also to the comment by @MLT, there is an alternative to the standard `cases` environment, not too sophisticated really, with both lines numbered. This code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{f(x)=}
  1, & if $x<0$\\
  0, & otherwise
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

Notice that here, math must be delimited by `\(...\)` or `$...$`, at least on the right of `&` in each line ([reference](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cases/cases.pdf)).

Comment: So numcases is basically an extension to cases? That's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & -\pi\leqslant x <0\\
\pi, & 0 \leqslant x \leqslant +\pi
\end{cases}
```

Comment: How is this different from the current answers?

Comment: This uses the cases package.  Which is described in better detail provided by @MattAllegro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to manually control the size of brace, if `cases` or `\left\{` doesn't provide suitable brace size you want.

```
\begin{math}
    \biggl\{
        \begin{array}{l}
            statement1\\
            statement2
        \end{array}
\end{math}
```

You can choose among `\bigl\{` `\Bigl\{` `\biggl\{` `\Biggl\{` to adjust brace size from the smallest to the largest.

[Image of different braces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIU1K.png)

From left to right: `cases` `\left\{` `biggl\{` `Bigl\{`