# How to write formula in Latex(Using Big Brackets)

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am new to the Latex code. I want to write the below formula in Latex

[image: GenaralFormula]

Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two statements next to curly brace in an equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027363/two-statements-next-to-curly-brace-in-an-equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
x = \begin{cases}
            0 & \text{true}\\
      1 & \text{false}
         \end{cases}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]